# Python sort multi dimensional dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
input={11: {'perc': 0, 'name': u'B test', 'cid': 11, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'complete': 0}, 10: {'perc': 0, 'name': u'C test', 'cid': 10, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0,'complete': 0}, 3: {'perc': 9, 'name': u'Atest Pre-requisites', 'cid': 3, 'total': 11, 'pending': 10, 'complete': 1}}
```

I want to sort this dict based on name field. I'm new in python, anyone please help me.

Comment: but dictionaries have their own sort order. What is your expected result?

Comment: sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
this will sort key value dict.

Comment: I want to sort based on name asc order

Comment: don't post your attempt in comments. [edit] your post instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should avoid using reserved words (such as `input`) as variables (now `input` is redefined and no longer calls the function `input()`).

Also, a dictionary cannot be sorted. If you don't need the keys, you can transform the dictionary into a list, and then sort it. The code would be like this:

```
input_dict = {11: {'perc': 0, 'name': u'B test', 'cid': 11, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'complete': 0}, 10: {'perc': 0, 'name': u'C test', 'cid': 10, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0,'complete': 0}, 3: {'perc': 9, 'name': u'Atest Pre-requisites', 'cid': 3, 'total': 11, 'pending': 10, 'complete': 1}}
input_list = sorted(input_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'])
print(input_list)
# prints [{'perc': 9, 'complete': 1, 'cid': 3, 'total': 11, 'pending': 10, 'name': u'Atest Pre-requisites'}, {'perc': 0, 'complete': 0, 'cid': 11, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'name': u'B test'}, {'perc': 0, 'complete': 0, 'cid': 10, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'name': u'C test'}]
```

**EDIT**

If you wish to keep the keys and use `iteritems()` as you said in the comments, use this code instead:

```
input_dict = {11: {'perc': 0, 'name': u'B test', 'cid': 11, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'complete': 0}, 10: {'perc': 0, 'name': u'C test', 'cid': 10, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0,'complete': 0}, 3: {'perc': 9, 'name': u'Atest Pre-requisites', 'cid': 3, 'total': 11, 'pending': 10, 'complete': 1}}
input_list = sorted(input_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['name'])
print(input_list)
# prints [(3, {'perc': 9, 'complete': 1, 'cid': 3, 'total': 11, 'pending': 10, 'name': u'Atest Pre-requisites'}), (11, {'perc': 0, 'complete': 0, 'cid': 11, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'name': u'B test'}), (10, {'perc': 0, 'complete': 0, 'cid': 10, 'total': 0, 'pending': 0, 'name': u'C test'})]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to show with key. This output doesn't have key.

Comment: Just added that to my answer!

Comment: You tried the whole code, or just the one line? I'll add the rest in case that's the problem

Comment: No, I tried the whole code. I replace the input_list line, but I was not printing anything

Comment: I am literally just copying and pasting the three lines, and it's printing fine. Maybe you are trying to use your original input and you didn't change the name of the variable to `input_dict`?