# Python Multi-Dimensional List/Dict: Sort by field?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to generate a python list with some dictionaries and then sort the list by using a specific object in the dictionaries, inside the list.

I have the following code:

```
data = {"data": []}

for client in clients:
    if client["network"] == "wireless":
        if "hostname" in client:
            if client["hostname"][0:3] == "PA_" or client["hostname"][0:3] == "PA-":
                item = {"{#HOSTNAME}": client["hostname"], "{#IP}": client["ip"], "{#MAC}": client["mac"],
                        "{#UPTME}": client["_uptime_by_uap"]}
                data["data"].append(item)

pprint(data)
```

It outputs exactly:

```
{'data': [{'{#HOSTNAME}': 'PA_abc',
           '{#IP}': '192.168.1.1',
           '{#MAC}': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
           '{#UPTME}': 540339},
          {'{#HOSTNAME}': 'PA-cxz',
           '{#IP}': '192.168.1.2',
           '{#MAC}': 'zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz',
           '{#UPTME}': 583768},
          {'{#HOSTNAME}': 'PA_jjj',
           '{#IP}': '192.168.1.3',
           '{#MAC}': 'cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc',
           '{#UPTME}': 1158902},
          {'{#HOSTNAME}': 'PA_BBB',
           '{#IP}': '192.168.1.4',
           '{#MAC}': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',
           '{#UPTME}': 1086962}]}
```

What i want to achieve is to print this list sorting by {#UPTME}...

I tried following a logic i found on [this article regarding list sorting](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort) and came up with:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('data'['{#UPTME}']))
```

But when i run it, i get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Also, i searched for this question here at Stack Overflow but saw multiple downvoted question, none of them solved for me. Before what I tried and the questions:

[Question 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157646/python-sort-multi-dimensional-dict)
Tried changing from #1 to #2, same error happened:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('data'['{#UPTME}'])) #1
input_list = sorted(data.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[0]['{#UPTME}']) #2
```

[Question 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary) Tried 2 methods specified there, marked as solved, but did'nt work also:

```
# Method #1 Test
newlist = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['{#UPTME}']) 
print(newlist)

# Method #2 Test
newlist2 = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('{#UPTME}')) 
print(newlist2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just made a slight mistake in calling sort on the dictionary instead of the array inside the dictionary.

try:

```
data['data'].sort(key=lambda x: x.get('{#UPTME}'))
```